# How to push mobile application (android/ios) logs to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

This apparently is so simple question but I have been trying hard and came accross many questions and articles but none of them really answers this.

There are many ways to design the architecture after the log is ingested and transferred to AWS. We can use ES, Kinesis and other services.

My problem is how to transfer the application client logs to AWS securly, anywhere, could be S3, Lambda, Kindesis, ElasticSearch. We can surely have an endpoint exposed but that will be open. How to authenticate this to make sure malicious users don't spam our logs? what is the best way to ingest and transfer logs to AWS from mobile applicatios?

Answer (score 0):

Creat an API that collect logs and ingest to kinesis expose it with API gateway use API keys aur authentication API to generate bearer token.
In application create functionality that make API call.
We did this in one of our application successfully

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use Amplify SDK on the client application to log
securely.

Have a look at this link:
https://medium.com/swlh/add-monitoring-to-your-amplify-app-by-using-amplify-framework-d4c43b2bb84b